# Android Fragment onCreateView with AsyncLayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-fragments

After founding out that my `onCreateView` took nearly a second to execute the `inflater.inflate(...)` method, I searched a bit and find out a new Class, `AsyncLayoutInflater`.

I tried to implement this constructor in my fragments but I can't figure out how to implement it properly since it always result into an empty blank view.

I think my problem is how to inflate my fragment having a null view returned from `onCreateView` (`super` result).

This is the "normal" version which works:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intervento_luogo, container, false);
    //do my stuffs
    return view;
}
```

This doesn't and shows up an empty view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AsyncLayoutInflater asyncLayoutInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getContext());
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intervento_luogo, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
            // do my stuffs
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I tried also putting this async inflater inside onResume, onViewCreated and onCreate but noone worked.

How should I implement this correctly? I can't believe there's no way to skip the inflation inside onCreateView doing it async.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create a `loading_view.xml` with a FrameLayout and a ProgressBar to show it while loading the other layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now you want to load asynchronously the other layout and attach it to the loading_view. You also want to hide the ProgressBar once the layout has been loaded.

```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        // inflate loading view
        val final_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view, container, false)
        // get progressbar
        var progressBar = final_view.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
        // initialize async layout inflater
        val asyncLayoutInflater = context?.let { AsyncLayoutInflater(it) }
        // inflate other layout
        asyncLayoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null) { view, resid, parent ->
            // when layout loaded show...
            (final_view as? ViewGroup)?.addView(view) // add view to already inflated view
        }

        return final_view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreateView(...) you create and return layout for fragment. Currently you return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); so it's blank and when your AsyncLayoutInflater is finished it is not affect your's fragment layout.

When your layout inflated - add it in your ViewGroup:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AsyncLayoutInflater asyncLayoutInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getContext());
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intervento_luogo, container, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
            parent.addView(view);
            onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

and also add onViewCreated to notify system what layout was created.

Code like this work for me:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val asyncLayoutInflater = AsyncLayoutInflater(context!!)
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_characters, container) { view, resid, parent ->
        binding = FragmentCharactersBinding.bind(view)
        binding.vm = vm
        container?.addView(binding.root)
        onViewCreated(binding.root, savedInstanceState)
    }

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried that but unfortunatly it's still showing blank page

Comment: Today I tried to reproduce your problem in my test project and face the same problem as you. I found what view created, added to container but onViewCreated not called so no fragment related data was initialised. I added onViewCreated at the end of asyncLayoutInflater to notify system about created view. I add the code above. Please check

Comment: Gotta say, if your context is null, this will throw a nullPointer. Consider using context?.let { val al = AsyncLayoutInflater(it) }

Comment: when would context be null in fragment's lifecycle?